# Adding more fields to SQL membership Provider for form-based authenticaiton

Tags: authentication, forms-authentication, sql-server

I have set up form-based authentication for SharePoint 2013 with .NET SQL Membership Provider.
It is working fine but I have requirement to add more fields for the users.

Will I have to write my own membership provider or is there any way I can make sql membership provider to work for this scenario.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Profile Provider for this, which let's you associate any arbitrary information you wish with the user.

Alternatively, you could create your own table(s) that store additional user-related information. This is a little more work since you're on the hook for creating your own tables and creating the code to get and save data to and from these tables.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2530113/using-asp-net-sql-membership-provider-how-do-i-store-my-own-per-user-data

http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/security/membership/storing-additional-user-information-cs

Answer (score 0):

I usually just use the membership provider only for authentication, and store the profile fields directly in SharePoint user's profile.